# Override Control Center screen edge pan from bottom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, control-center

I’d like to use a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` on the bottom edge of my display. The recognizer works perfectly if I set its `edges` to `UIRectEdgeLeft` or `UIRectEdgeRight`, but `UIRectEdgeTop` or `UIRectEdgeBottom` do not work – they’ve overridden by some `UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer`.

I’m actually trying to override the Control Center in the same way that Facebook Paper has managed to do – figured the screen edge pan may have been their trick. Paper allows you to scroll from the bottom screen edge to pull their menu up, and Control Center doesn’t pop up at all. It’s definitely possible, I’m just wondering how they’ve done it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick that lets you prevent the accidental launch of the Control Center. Just disable the status bar. Then on swipe the user will be prompted whether the control centre have to be launched or not.

It won't be launched in a single swipe. Instead an arrow appears on the first swipe and the user need to click and drag the arrow to launch the control centre, hence prevent accidental launch. Use this code to disable status bar.

I don't know if it will work in your case and your gesture recognizer will be fired but I would give it a try.

You can disable the status bar using this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to go one step further and disable it entirely. If you're in the US, grab the Facebook Paper app and try that out – they've managed to do it somehow, I'm really curious on how! :)

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to disable it completely. Users expect to launch the control center in this way. I wouldn't be surprised if Apple validation team doesn't like it neither.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but because the Facebook app hides the status bar they happen have the same behavior as in all full-screen apps in iOS.

I have tested it multiple times - the `Control Center` does not pop up, but the little tiny arrow to bring it up - does.

So your assumption is wrong - Facebook **didn't disable** `Control Center`, nor did they override any behaviors. The just hid the statusBar across the whole app.

Just set the key value `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in `plist`. Then hide it.

And it is the way to go.

And BTW, when you swipe the apps view down to reveal your profile and the status bar appears - try to swipe up from the very bottom edge of the screen. Believe me, you'll be totally amazed.

There's no magic here, no nothing. Facebook are big but they can't defy iOS rules. And I'd like it to be that way, honestly.

Here's the video of the process:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2CWvhxhGoY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Are you looking specifically at Facebook Paper, not plain ol' vanilla Facebook? It's Paper that does it, it's only available in the US store – one of the guys here has it on his device, I will check and verify, but he seemed damned sure they still showed the status bar.

Comment: @lukech, of course, that's 200%. Facebook Paper, the latest update

Comment: Okay, I've verified it. Pull down the navigation from the top of the screen in Paper, then while it's open, try to pull up from the bottom of the screen to pull the rest of the app back up. The status bar is visible at that point, but there's not even the little nub for Control Center there when you try it, absolutely no response from Control Center at all. I verified that the status bar itself updates too, so I don't think they're showing a fake status bar or anything like that.

Comment: @lukech We're talking about the very edge of the screen here. I've tested it in different apps and it all behaves the same, I'm telling you.

Comment: Here’s a screenshot:
http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/photo-3.png?w=216&h=384
Get to this screen, then pull up from the bottom screen edge, as you would to trigger Control Center, from the very edge. You won’t see Control Center, and you won’t see the nub for it, either.

Comment: @lukech That's the screen I've been taking about. Believe me or not, I'm having a control center there. **Period**

Comment: Hmm, well I am most definitely not, which is kinda interesting in itself.

Comment: @lukech Make sure you have Control Center on for the apps and make sure to start the finger gesture slightly off the screen, near the home button - you'll see what I'm talking about

Comment: That’s exactly my situation I’m afraid, I’m not doing anything wrong, it’s just not opening Control Center if I swipe up from off-screen on the bottom edge when the nav is open. It opens it as normal throughout the rest of the app (that is, with the little nub since the rest of the app hides the status bar) – I’m convinced they’ve overridden it somehow in that instance.

Comment: @lukechcheck out the updated answer for video proof.

Comment: That's really interesting. I'm doing the exact same thing and there's no Control Center, but only in that specific instance. I'm still convinced there's something happening there, so I think the question still stands even if your device / version isn't triggering it.

Comment: @lukech No, nothing's happening there, I've checked multiple devices and they all act the same. iOS 7.1.2, same behavior everywhere. 100% it will be the same everywhere. All have the latest version.

Comment: So I’ve confirmed that this behaviour existed in an older version of Paper. We’re based in the UK and don’t get automatic updates from the US App Store. We did an update, and it went away. Most definitely was in there, though, so I suppose they did something Apple didn’t like. As an aside, have you noticed that the status bar text is not fully white in Paper too? Seems like that’s another thing they’ve managed to hack together.

Comment: @lukech Yeah, just discussed that yesterday with my colleague. They also managed to overlay a view on top of the status bar when you slide it up. Looks quite strange but I don't think we can repeat after them.

Comment: I know that the snapshot methods in iOS7 will capture the status bar, so they must be doing something like that to move it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using UISwipeGestureRecognizer instead?